# Jquery - scripts don't work in a modal window (Pretty Photo)

Tags: jquery

Is there any way how to force scripts to work in a modal window (PrettyPhoto)?

[WYSIWYG-BBCODE editor](http://www.sceditor.com/) and [Jquery Tokenize script](http://zellerda.com/projects/jquery/tokenize) work on a normal page but not in a modal window. No Javascript errors, nothing.

Tried to add

```
jQuery(function($){$(document).ready(function(){
```

before but it does not help.

Jquery is included in the parent page.

**Script1**

```
<script src="//mywebsite/jquery.tokenize.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('select#kid_m').tokenize({displayDropdownOnFocus:true,
placeholder:"To",
autosize:true
});                         
</script>
<select id="kid_m" name="kid_m[]" class="tokenize-sample" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

**Script2**

```
<script src="mywebsite/sce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$("textarea").sceditor({
plugins: 'bbcode',
toolbar: "bold,italic,underline,quote,bulletlist,emoticon,color,youtube|removeformat,source",
emoticonsCompat:true,
enablePasteFiltering:true,
bbcodeTrim:true
});
});
var bbcodes = ['s', 'sub', 'sup', 'font', 'size', 'list', 'ol', '*','table', 'tr', 'th',  'td', 'horizontalrule',  'img', 'url', 'email','code', 'left', 'center', 'right', 'justify', 'rtl', 'ltr', 'hr'];
$.each(bbcodes, function(idx, bbcode) { $.sceditorBBCodePlugin.bbcode.remove(bbcode);});
</script>

<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
```

Comment: Is the modal window opening a different page?

Comment: No. I use PrettyPhoto to show modal windows. PrettyPhoto script itself works OK but scripts included in a modal wondow - not.